# R for loop to compute correlation between one x and multiple y variables

Tags: r

I am trying to compute the correlation of one x variable with multiple y variables.
I am using a for loop similar to this code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                 var1 = rnorm(100),
                 var2 = rnorm(100),
                 var3 = rnorm(100))

for (y in grep("var", colnames(df), value = TRUE)) {
  summarise(df, cor(x, y))
}
```

Receiving the following error message:

> ```
> Error in `summarise()`:
> ! Problem while computing `..1 = cor(x, y)`.
> Caused by error in `cor()`:
> ! 'y' must be numeric
> ```

My guess is, that the "y" in the correlation-function is not being interpreted as a variable name.
Does someone have any hints on how to fix this?

Comment: You may want to consider forming a correlation matrix directly, using packages such as [corrr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrr/corrr.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr::across` you could do:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                 var1 = rnorm(100),
                 var2 = rnorm(100),
                 var3 = rnorm(100))

library(dplyr)

summarise(df, across(!x, ~ cor(x, .x)))
#>          var1      var2      var3
#> 1 -0.04953215 -0.129176 -0.044079
```